# knitting a figure to word using papaja fails

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, pandoc, papaja

I am able to knit the following code to PDF. However, it always fails when trying to knit the output to Word (win 10, Rstudio 1.2.5033, R 3.6.2, papaja 0.1.0.9942). I had to delete the papaja header for posting (too much code).

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("papaja")
```

# Methods

```{r figure}
plot(cars)
```
````

The error message reads

> Error running filter D:/Boelte/R_library/papaja/rmd/docx_fixes.lua:
>   [string "--[[..."]:227: Constructor for Emph failed: [string
>   "--[[..."]:258: attempt to index     a nil value (local 'x')
>        stack traceback: [C]: in function 'error' 
>         ..."]:227: in field 'Emph' D:/Boelte/R_library/papaja/rmd/docx_fixes.lua:14: in function 'Image'
>       Fehler: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83

Is there any way to correct this error? It is a papaja or a pandoc error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `papaja` error related to post-processing of the document (in this case styling figure captions) via the `docx_fixes.lua`-filter. I will try to fix this as soon as possible. For the time being, you should be able to resolve this problem by specifying a figure caption in the chunk options.

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("papaja")
```

# Methods

(ref:fig-cap) This is the figure caption.

```{r figure, fig.cap = "(ref:fig-cap)"}
plot(cars)
```
````